# python os.path.dirname yields wrong results with windows network path

Tags: python, string, windows, dirname

I've got this code snippet

```
print "tmp = ", tmp
print "dirname = ", os.path.dirname(tmp)
print "tmp sane = ", (os.path.dirname(tmp.replace("\\", "/"))).replace("/", "\\")
```

that produces this result

```
tmp =  \\aaaa.aaa\aaaaaaaa\aaaaaaaaa\aaaa\aaaa\aaaaa\aaaaaaa\aaaaaaa\aaaa.aaaaaaaa_aaaaaa\aa\aaaaa\aaaaaa\aaa\aaaaaa\aa\aaaaa\aaaaaaa_aaaaaaaaa_aaa\aaaa_aa.aaa
dirname =
tmp sane =  \\aaaa.aaa\aaaaaaaa\aaaaaaaaa\aaaa\aaaa\aaaaa\aaaaaaa\aaaaaaa\aaaa.aaaaaaaa_aaaaaa\aa\aaaaa\aaaaaa\aaa\aaaaaa\aa\aaaaa\aaaaaaa_aaaaaaaaa_aaa
```

Any ideas why "tmp sane" works and the simple dirname doesn't? I couldn't find anything related to the windows network names/backslashes.

Comment: Can you show us the same information using `repr(tmp)`, `repr(os.path.dirname(tmp))`, etc.? Also, what platform is this, are you running this on *Windows* or *something else*?

Comment: It's cygwin under windows. `repr(tmp)` prints out `'\\\\aaaa.aaa\\aaaaaaaa\\aaaaaaaaa\\aaaa\\aaaa\\aaaaa\\aaaaaaa\\aaaaaaa\\aaaa.aaaaaaaa_aaaaaa\\aa\\aaaaa\\aaaaaa\\aaa\\aaaaaa\\aa\\aaaaa\\aaaaaaa_aaaaaaaaa_aaa\\aaaa_aa.aaa'`

Comment: Cygwin is a POSIX implementation, so `os.path == posixpath`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are most likely not running this on Windows. The behaviour is entirely consistent with using the `os.path` module on anything but an actual Windows environment.

`os.path` adjusts behaviour to match the current platform. On Windows, both forward and backward slashes are supported, but on Linux and Mac only forward slashes are recognized. That's to match the actual convention used on the platform you are running your code on.

If you want to split dirnames from Windows paths on a POSIX OS like Mac OS X or Linux, you'll need to import the `ntpath` module; that module is what is really used on Windows but it is available still on other platforms:

```
import ntpath
result = ntpath.dirname(path)
```

See the top of the [`os.path` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html):

> **Note**: Since different operating systems have different path name conventions, there are several versions of this module in the standard library. The `os.path` module is always the path module suitable for the operating system Python is running on, and therefore usable for local paths. However, you can also import and use the individual modules if you want to manipulate a path that is *always* in one of the different formats. They all have the same interface:
>
> - `posixpath` for UNIX-style paths
> - `ntpath` for Windows paths
> - `macpath` for old-style MacOS paths
> - `os2emxpath` for OS/2 EMX paths

Cygwin is considered a POSIX environment, not Windows, in this context.